# Error CS1061 - Button1_click ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a button, which On click, will store textboxes into a db, using `generalcontext db connection.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SaveCVInfo2();
}

private void SaveCVInfo2()
{
   using (ConexionGeneralDataContext db = new ConexionGeneralDataContext())
   {
      Usuario_Web columna = new Usuario_Web();
  //Add new values to each fields
  columna.Nombre = nombre.Text;
  columna.Apellido = Apellidos.Text;
  columna.Em_solicitado = Empleo.Text;
  columna.Direccion = DireccionPersonal.Text;
  columna.Ciudad = Ciudad.Text;
  columna.Tel_habitacion = TelHabi.Text;
  columna.Celular = TelCel.Text;
  columna.Email = userEmail.Text;
  columna.Nacionalidad = Nacionalidad.Text;

  //Insert the new Customer object
  db.Usuario_Web.InsertOnSubmit(columna);
  //Sumbit changes to the database
  db.SubmitChanges();
   }
}
```

And I have a previous method, in the same codebehind file, called `Register`:

```
protected void Register(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (emailValid())
   {
      string[] extension = { "go" };
      int last = 0;

      bool validFile = true;
      if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
      {
         extension = FileUpload1.FileName.Split('.');
         last = extension.Length - 1;

         if (String.Compare(extension[last], "DOC", true) != 0 && String.Compare(extension[last], "DOCX", true) != 0 && String.Compare(extension[last], "PDF", true) != 0)
         {
            validFile = false;
         }
      }

  if (validFile)
      {
         ConexionGeneralDataContext db = new ConexionGeneralDataContext();
         Usuario_Web columna = new Usuario_Web();

         columna.Estatus = 1;
         columna.Fecha_hora = DateTime.Now;
         columna.Nombre = nombre.Text;
         columna.Email = userEmail.Text;
     columna.Contraseña = classes.main.MD5(contraseña.Text); 

         if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
         {
            string path = Server.MapPath("Default.aspx");
            path = path.Replace("Default.aspx", "");
            path = path + "CurriculumsVitae\\";

            Random randomNumber = new Random();
            string filename = randomNumber.Next(10000000, 99999999).ToString() + FileUpload1.FileName;

            string ubicacionReal = createPath(path) + filename;
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(ubicacionReal);
            columna.Curriculum_vitae = ubicacionReal;
         }
     db.Usuario_Web.InsertOnSubmit(columna);
         db.SubmitChanges();

         MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
         email.From = new MailAddress("administrador@grupozulcon.com.ve", "Grupo Zulcon");
         email.To.Add(userEmail.Text);
         email.Subject = "¡Bienvenido a nuestra comunidad!";

         email.Body = "<div>Gracias por registrarte.</div><div style=\"margin-top:10px\">Estamos altamente comprometidos con tu desarrollo, por ello, te ofrecemos las mejores ofertas laborales.</div><div style=\"margin-top:10px\">Visítanos y postúlate a los cargos que se adapten a tu perfil.</div><div style=\"margin-top:10px\">Mantén tu CV actualizado. Puedes leer nuestra sección “Consejos” si tienes alguna duda en la elaboración del mismo.</div><div style=\"margin-top:10px\">Te contactaremos en caso de tener ofertas de empleo que se ajusten a tu perfil.</div><div style=\"margin-top:10px\">¡Éxito!</div>";

         email.IsBodyHtml = true;

         SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
         smtp.Send(email);


         double timeout = 120;
         string identity = columna.ID + "|&*#$|" + columna.Nombre + "|&*#$|" + columna.Email + "|&*#$|" + convertCVPath(columna.Curriculum_vitae) + convert;

         FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, identity, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout), false, identity);

         string hashedCookie = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
         HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashedCookie);

         Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
         PanelAutenticacion.Visible = false;
         PanelRespuesta.Visible = true;
   }

   else
   {
      PanelEmail.Visible = false;
      PanelArchivo.Visible = true;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            PanelEmail.Visible = true;
            PanelArchivo.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

However, i'm adding multiple buttons, of multiple pages, which share same `codebehind` file.

But, when i add `Button1_Click` besides `Register`, then `Register` starts throwing errors:

```
Error   44  Se esperaba una clase, un delegado, una enumeración, una interfaz o un struct   C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon - copia\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs   51  19  Grupo Zulcon
Error   45  Se esperaba un identificador    C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon - copia\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs   55  24  Grupo Zulcon
Error   46  Se esperaba una clase, un delegado, una enumeración, una interfaz o un struct   C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon - copia\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs   55  26  Grupo Zulcon
Error   47  Se esperaba una clase, un delegado, una enumeración, una interfaz o un struct   C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon - copia\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs   64  55  Grupo Zulcon
Error   48  Se esperaba una clase, un delegado, una enumeración, una interfaz o un struct   C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon - copia\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs   64  108 Grupo Zulcon
Error   49  Se esperaba una clase, un delegado, una enumeración, una interfaz o un struct   C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon - copia\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs   64  162 Grupo Zulcon
Error   50  Un espacio de nombres no puede contener directamente miembros como campos o métodos.    C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon - copia\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs   74  17  Grupo Zulcon
Error   51  Se esperaba una clase, un delegado, una enumeración, una interfaz o un struct   C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon - copia\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs   76  57  Grupo Zulcon
Error   52  Se esperaba una clase, un delegado, una enumeración, una interfaz o un struct   C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon - copia\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs   78  47  Grupo Zulcon
Error   53  Se esperaba una clase, un delegado, una enumeración, una interfaz o un struct   C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon - copia\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs   92  51  Grupo Zulcon
Error   54  Se esperaba una definición de tipo o espacio de nombres, o el fin del archivo   C:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon - copia\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs   99  21  Grupo Zulcon
```

I don't understand why, i need to add 8 more methods (buttons) to this `aspx.cs` codebehind file, every method would be used in a different `aspx` page, all of them part of this Visual Studio solution.

EDIT

If i leave just `Register` method alone, it won't throw any errors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Additional**: My suggestion would be the following:

I would not let pages use the same code behind file over 8 pages. Rather created a helper class (Helper.cs) that you can call these method i.e. `SaveCVInfo2` and `Register` from.

`SaveCVInfo2` method will look like this in the Helper class

```
public void SaveCVInfo2(string varOne,string varTwo, string  varThree...)
{
   using (ConexionGeneralDataContext db = new ConexionGeneralDataContext())
   {
      Usuario_Web columna = new Usuario_Web();
      //Add new values to each fields
      columna.Nombre = varOne;
      columna.Apellido = varTwo;
      columna.Em_solicitado = varThree;
      //and the rest where the textboxes would have been


      //Insert the new Customer object
      db.Usuario_Web.InsertOnSubmit(columna);
      //Sumbit changes to the database
      db.SubmitChanges();
   }

}
```

Then it will be reference as

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Helper helper = new Helper();
    helper.SaveCVInfo2(nombre.Text,Apellidos.Text,Empleo.Text,...);
}
```

The same for `Register`. These can then easily be reused be reused on the other 8 pages.

If you reuse the method rather share it.  SOLID principals should apply.

Comment: WoW, that is an advice, lol, thank you, i'm going to try it! And will let you know, thx!

Comment: Excuse me, one dumb question, i'm still mastering asp.net, what should i write between '{}' after 'public void SaveCVInfo2' declaration?

Comment: Or just put empty '{}' after public void SaveCVInfo2(string varOne,string varTwo, string varThree...)?

Comment: I added more detail to my answer after your comments. Hope it helps.

Comment: WoW, thank you so much, as soon as i get home i'll try it =), btw, every button will be at codebehind aspx.cs, (Button1_Click, Button2_Click, Button3_Click...) and will reference the helper object i'm instantiating, right? all instantiated from helper.cs (SaveCVInfo2, SaveCVInfo3, SaveCVInfo4...) if i understood right :)

Comment: This line gives me problems, i do the steps just as you said, in just the first page, just to give it a try "<div style="text-align:right; margin-top:20px"><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Curriculum" OnClick="Button1_Click" postbackurl="Envia2.aspx" CssClass="my_btn" /></div>
" CS1061 error :(

Comment: ''ASP.envianostucurriculum_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button1_Click' and found no extension method 'Button1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.envianostucurriculum_aspx' (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?'

Comment: Solved! Done! You were right! It works like a charm! Thank you! Now i got another minor thing but i'm going to open a new question for that! Thx Thx and Thx again!

Comment: Awesome! If it helped and you feel like it please give me a right mark for the answer or up vote. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: If you want to be a superstar programmer just stick to SOLID - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60845/The-S-O-L-I-D-Object-Oriented-Programming-OOP-Prin

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it was a `}` not needed.